# Org-mode deadline: Repeat certain number of times

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I'm looking for a way to specify a deadline in org-mode that repeats at certain intervals but only a specified number of times.

For instance, if I want to have a deadline repeat twice one week apart, I can make it appear in the agenda using diary-date:

```
   DEADLINE: <%%(diary-date 4 '(19 26) 2018)>
```

But it throws a `Could not find timestamp` error when I try to mark it `DONE` in agenda view.

I can also make it repeat indefinitely with `<4-19-2018 +1w>` then manually mark it `DONE` after a certain number of weeks using the numeric prefix -1, but that increases cognitive load.

I'm looking for an out-of-the-box solution before trying any custom elisp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to clone the subtree. Say you have

```
** TODO give Kyle money
DEADLINE: <2018-04-28 Sat>
```

You can clone the subtree with `org-clone-subtree-with-time-shift` (<kbd>C-c C-x c</kbd>).  To create a single clone one week later, enter "1" in the first prompt and "+1w"  in the second.  The end result would then be

```
** TODO give Kyle money
DEADLINE: <2018-04-28 Sat>
** TODO give Kyle money
DEADLINE: <2018-05-05 Sat>
```